# Fallo al subir imágenes al servidor

Tags: php, imagen, servidor

Quería hacer un formulario donde pueda añadir imágenes de una carpeta local y guardarlas en un servidor.
Tengo este código html:

```
 <div align="center">
    <h1>INICIO DE USUARIO</h1>
    <form method="post" action="subir-imagen1.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Subir imagen: <input type="file" name="file[]" multiple>
        <input type="submit" value="Subir imagen" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Y este es el php al que llevo cuando le doy a enviar:

```
<?php

if (isset($_FILES["file"])){

$reporte = null;

for($x=0; $x<count($_FILES["file"]["name"]); $x++){

  $file = $_FILES["file"];
  $nombre = $file["name"][$x];
  $tipo = $file["type"][$x];
  $ruta_provisional = $file["tmp_name"][$x];
  $size = $file["size"][$x];
  $dimensiones = getimagesize($ruta_provisional);
  $width = $dimensiones[0];
  $height = $dimensiones[1];
  $carpeta = "ftp://servidor.es/Richard/Marcas/Imagenes/";

  if ($tipo != 'image/jpeg' && $tipo != 'image/jpg' && $tipo != 'image/png' && $tipo != 'image/gif'){
      $reporte .= "<p style='color: red'>Error $nombre, el archivo no es una imagen.</p>";
  }
  else if($size > 3000*3000){
      $reporte .= "<p style='color: red'>Error $nombre, el tamaño máximo permitido es 1mb</p>";
  }
  else if($width > 3000 || $height > 3000){
      $reporte .= "<p style='color: red'>Error $nombre, la anchura y la altura máxima permitida es de 3000px</p>";
  }
  else if($width < 60 || $height < 60){
      $reporte .= "<p style='color: red'>Error $nombre, la anchura y la altura mínima permitida es de 60px</p>";
  }

  else{
      $src = $carpeta.$nombre;

      //Caragamos imagenes al servidor
      move_uploaded_file($ruta_provisional, $src);       

      //Codigo para insertar imagenes a tu Base de datos.
      //Sentencia SQL

      echo "<p style='color: blue'>La imagen $nombre ha sido subida con éxito</p>";
  }
}

echo $reporte;
}
```

Y no consigo que funcione nunca, me salen estos errores, a ver si me podéis ayudar, gracias!

> Warning:
>   move_uploaded_file(ftp://servidor.es/Richard/Marcas/Imagenes/tigre.jpg):
>   failed to open stream: operation failed in
>   /var/www/vhosts/16/181528/webspace/httpdocs/servidor.es/alumnos/Richard/Marcas/Usuario/subir-imagen1.php
>   on line 65 Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move
>   '/tmp/phpolJTQ0' to
>   'ftp://servidor.es/Richard/Marcas/Imagenes/tigre.jpg' in
>   /var/www/vhosts/16/181528/webspace/httpdocs/servidor.es/alumnos/Richard/Marcas/Usuar

io/subir-imagen1.php on line 65

Comment: revisa la permisología de los archivos, puede que no este subiendo la imagen porque la carpeta a donde apuntas a guardarla no posee los permisos necesarios. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza **DIR** delante de las rutas para hacer referencia al archivo que se esta ejecutando (en tu caso el archivo con el codigo php), así se aseguras de que la ruta existe.
Ejemplo:

```
$carpeta = __DIR__ . "/";
```

Con esto se te debería guardar en la misma carpeta en la que se encuentra el archivo .php que ejecuta el script. Si se te guarda ya sabes que es un problema de rutas y siempre puedes usar "**../**" para ir cambiando de directorios.

Answer (score -1):

El error me parece que esta en la ruta a la carpeta

```
$carpeta = "ftp://servidor.es/Richard/Marcas/Imagenes/";
```

No es necesario poner el protocolo "ftp", es más yo usaría rutas relativas, por ejemplo si tu **subir-imagen1.php** esta en "servidor.es/Richard/subir-imagen1.php", la ruta de $carpeta sería esta:

```
$carpeta = "Marcas/Imagenes/";
```

Date cuenta que estas moviendo un archivo de una ruta normal '/tmp/phpolJTQ0' a una ruta por protocolo ftp. Prueba a usar rutas relativas y sin poner ningun protocolo en el enlace y me cuentas.

Comment: Si, tienes razón, de hecho la acabo de cambiar, ahora es: $carpeta = "../Imagenes/"; pero sigue sin subirse al servidor...lo raro es que no me da errores ahora, pero no se sube al servidor. @CobasEsp

Comment: Imprimete por pantalla con un echo la ruta a la imagen temporal en tmp y asegurate que al menos la imagen se esta subiendo correctamente a la carpeta temporal y  así podemos saber si es un fallo a la hora de mover el archivo o es que directamente no se te suben al server las imagenes